# No signal found Spectre X40 LCD TV, hdmi

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, tv, external-display

I hope this is relevant to this forum.  I am attempting to connect a small Android powered device with an HDMI output to a Spectre X40 LCD Television.  No matter which port I use, I still receive a "No Signal Found" message.  I have successfully connected the device to a ASUS monitor via HDMI, it works perfectly.   I have also successfully connected a PC via a DVI - HDMI adapter to the TV, and am able to support a 1080p image.  I have tried two separate HMDI cables.  Would it be some kind of incompatibility in the device?  Should I keep attempting to change resolutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working...... Tried 1080p 50Hz , tried this earlier and it didn't work not sure what changed now.  Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Uh I'm answering myself, just saying thanks to those who may have taken the time to read through my post. Above is what fixed it.